# How can I upload a file from AngularJS application to Firebase Hosting

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, ng-file-upload

I am using Firebase Hosting to host my AngularJS application. I am using ng-file-upload to grab the user-uploaded image from a form I already have in my application. I want to store the user-uploaded image in a folder on my Firebase Hosting. I cannot use Firebase Storage because I need a pre-determined, direct link to the image resource in various parts of my platform. I thought that maybe I could use Firebase Functions to upload the file and store it in my Firebase Hosting. I keep running into cross-origin errors.

Could someone explain how to structure the Firebase Function so I can upload the image to my Firebase Hosting? From what I understand, the Firebase Function is not hosted at the same location as the rest of the Firebase Hosting content, but I am not sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is exclusively for versioned, deployed static content. Cloud Storage for Firebase is definitely the right product for you. When you say you need a "pre-determined direct link" do you mean you need to be able to know the URL before the upload completes? If not, you can just use [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) in the Firebase Cloud Storage SDK.

If you do need to know the URL in advance, you could do the following:

1. [Upload the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) to Cloud Storage using the Firebase SDK.
2. [Create a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) that listens for uploads.
3. In the function, use the [GCS Node API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#storage-make-object-public-nodejs) to make the object public.

Once you do the above, your file will be directly and publicly accessible at `https://<bucket>.storage.googleapis.com/<path_to_object>`.