# can i store files in my functions folder dynamically in nodejs when hosting from firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage

I am hosting my site using firebase hosting and am using express app for firebase functions . When the client sends an image in a form data , i want to store this image inside the `functions` folder of firebase .

Is this allowed to do ? If not what's the workaround for this ?

Also if its not possible how to upload the image file to firebase directly storage without writing the image file data to a file. Since upload function only takes a local file path to send...

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to upload files to Firebase Hosting, it is purely meant for hosting static assets that you create during development. Also see [How can I upload a file from AngularJS application to Firebase Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746594/how-can-i-upload-a-file-from-angularjs-application-to-firebase-hosting)

Images that your users generate (often referred to as "user-generate content") can be stored in Cloud Storage, either directly from the client-side by using its [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) or from your server-side Express code through the [Node SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage).